# Ending slogin session with exit command freezes due to PROMPT_COMMAND modification

Tags: ssh, alias, bashrc, exit

I recently embedded an "`alert`" command into my `PROMPT_COMMAND` to give me a little `notify-send` screen notification with the exit code of each command (because I always forget to append the `alert` when a long-running job is started).

That works like a charm, but then I discovered a minor nuisance about it:

When I connect to another computer in my network via slogin and want to disconnect with `exit`, it states "logout" and then just sits there.
When I press [ctrl]+[c] it is back to my local session without a problem.
I figured out that if I chuck out the "auto-`alert`" in all SSH-sessions the problem disappears. It's not that big of a deal, but I just wonder what is happening and maybe how to fix it, if possible.

Here's the command (in my aliases):

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? -eq 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history 1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

And this is in my .bashrc:

```
if [[ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" != alert* ]]; then # && ([ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -z "$SSH_TTY" ]); then
  PROMPT_COMMAND="alert; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

If i add the comment to the line (remove `; then #`), the slogin session exits immediately without a problem (but also doesn't notify me of long-running jobs ending, of course).

Comment: A marginal comment on your first code section: you could advantageously replace `history | tail -n1`  with `history 1`, I think. Also if you are testing arithmetic values in bash, go for `[ $? -eq 0 ]` or if you test on strings, go for: `[ "$?" == "0" ] `. In the latter form a single `=` sign is also accepted.  Mixing things up is a good recipe for issues.

Comment: @Cbhihe Thanks for the suggestions, I edited the script for these two minor "issues". Had not even thought about "history 1", very neat. Sadly, both changes had no effect on the logout procedure..